# Prevent numbered parameters when registring a controller route

Tags: php, laravel-4

Laravel has a marvelous routing system but I am struggling with one bit in particular.

I want to remove the extra optional routes created when I define a controller for a route.

In Laravel 3 you could apparently do the following but never having worked with v3 I don't know if this is what I am looking for, at any rate, it doesn't work in v4.

```
Router::$segments = 0;
```

For instance when I define my routes like this:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'monitoring'), function() {
    // Handle hosts
    Route::controller('hosts/', 'Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index');
    Route::controller('hosts/{host}', 'Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host');
    Route::controller('hosts/{host}/{service}', 'Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service');
});
```

My routes will show up like this in `artisan routes` command:

```
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
| Domain | URI                                                                                            | Name | Action                                                  | Before Filters | After Filters |
+--------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------------+
|        | GET|HEAD /                                                                                     |      | Closure                                                 |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/status/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                        |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getStatus        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/details/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                       |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getDetails       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/report/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                        |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getReport        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/thresholds/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                    |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getThresholds    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/timeline/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                      |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getTimeline      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                         |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getIndex         |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts                                                                      |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Index@getIndex         |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/status/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                 |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getStatus         |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/details/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getDetails        |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/report/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                 |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getReport         |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/thresholds/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}             |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getThresholds     |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/timeline/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}               |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getTimeline       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}                  |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getIndex          |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}                                                               |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Host@getIndex          |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/status/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getStatus      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/details/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}      |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getDetails     |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/report/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}       |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getReport      |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/thresholds/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}   |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getThresholds  |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/timeline/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}     |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getTimeline    |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/self-healing/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?} |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getSelfHealing |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}/index/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}        |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getIndex       |                |               |
|        | GET|HEAD monitoring/hosts/{host}/{service}                                                     |      | Apm\Controllers\Monitoring\Hosts\Service@getIndex       |                |               |
```

Simply said, I want to get rid of the `{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}` part since I can always predict my parameters and more often than not I want to dictate the controller that must be used and name them.

**Update**
We decided against implicitly listing all routes because that would make our routes.php extremely bloated (hundreds if not thousands of routes would have to be made). The controller setup like we have now works perfectly, aside from the extra parameters the router parses, something which is not present when implicitly defining a route with `Route::get`.

I should probably mention we modified the `Router` class slightly to be able to make sub-resources a possibility.

Comment: How do the methods of your controller look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, what we had already done is making an override for the `Router` class. I understand now that this is also key for the resolution of this question.

The `Route::controller` basically enables you to register all the methods in it implicitly as end-points for routes. This is, as mentioned, not something you'd want to do normally, but we made an informed decision before going this way. To solve the problem of not properly being able to say which parameters can be passed to the function, they add these 5 'wildcard' parameters. We/in the question we use classes in such a way that these parameters are not necessary.

I would like to note that this could probably be solved using more reflection magic using `ReflectionMethod::getParameters`. Though, there's also plenty to say against using something like that as well.

So, as you might have guessed, in short, Laravel uses a reflection class of the class you pass to the `Route::controller` and extracts the route endpoints from the code this way.

The parameters are added in the class `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector@addUriWildcards` so to prevent the addition of these parameters we need to make an override of this class. And because this class is instantiated and then used in the `Illuminate\Routing\Router` class we will also need to override the `Router`.

In Laravel you're required to make an [IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc) to create an override for core classes. For `Router` this is no different. Though the standard documentation (currently) is not particularly clear on how to do this.

(We implemented psr-4 and set the namespace `Apm` to `app/` for autoloading my classes)

In `app/Lib/Routing/RoutingServiceProvider.php`

```
<?php namespace Apm\Lib\Routing;
use Illuminate\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider as LaravelRoutingServiceProvider;

class RoutingServiceProvider extends LaravelRoutingServiceProvider
{
    protected function registerRouter()
    {
        $this->app['router'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            $router = new Router($app['events'], $app);

            // If the current application environment is "testing", we will disable the
            // routing filters, since they can be tested independently of the routes
            // and just get in the way of our typical controller testing concerns.
            if ($app['env'] == 'testing')
            {
                $router->disableFilters();
            }

            return $router;
        });
    }
}
```

This sets the Router class to be used to `Apm\Lib\Routing\Router`, replacing `Illuminate\Routing\Router`.

So in `app/Lib/Routing/Router.php` we have

```
<?php namespace Apm\Lib\Routing;
use Illuminate\Routing\Router as LaravelRouter;

class Router extends LaravelRouter
{
    /**
     * Get a controller inspector instance.
     *
     * @return \Apm\Lib\Routing\ControllerInspector
     */
    public function getInspector()
    {
        return $this->inspector ?: $this->inspector = new ControllerInspector;
    }
}
```

Which sets the Controller Inspector to `Apm\Lib\Routing\ControllerInspector` instead of `Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector`.

And finally in `app/Lib/Routing/ControllerInspector.php` we have:

```
<?php namespace Apm\Lib\Routing;
use Illuminate\Routing\ControllerInspector as LaravelControllerInspector;

class ControllerInspector extends LaravelControllerInspector
{
    /**
     * Add wildcards to the given URI.
     *
     * @param  string  $uri
     * @return string
     */
    public function addUriWildcards($uri)
    {
        return $uri;//.'/{one?}/{two?}/{three?}/{four?}/{five?}';
    }
}
```

Then to make sure Laravel uses our classes instead of its own, we need to register the Service Provider in `app/config/app.php` in the `'providers'` array.

```
'providers' => array(
        'Apm\Lib\Routing\RoutingServiceProvider',
),
```

Ofcourse it would be much better to somehow be able to pass the parameters to be used for each endpoint/function method explicitly, but that defeats the point of implicitly setting the endpoints.

If using this mechanism anyway, you might want to go a step further and get/use the route parameters based on the parameters accepted by the method. While not adding parameters already set in the base route pattern for the controller being inspected.

Enfin, this solved the problem for us as we do not need the parameters added to the end of the routes anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with a way that you could get rid of these extra parameters, but using implicit routing is not considered a best practice and potentially can lead to many problems. Check out [this post](http://philsturgeon.co.uk/blog/2013/07/beware-the-route-to-evil) for more info. If you can predict, as you say, the parameters i think its better to explicitly define your routes with `Route::get` etc.

Comment: This issue has been evaluated internally before we decided to take this approach. I've read the article you linked and besides a few technical inaccuracies (Sub-Resources are possible, endpoints are layed out exactly with artisan routes) it makes valid points, but for the scale of this project we decided not to implicitly name all routes, because it would interfere with the last point in that article, namely a routes.php with hundreds if not thousand lines of code. Also, this is not an answer, and should be a comment.